High Latency Issue with Paddle OCR on IP Camera Text Extraction
Preprocessing frames with blur and adaptive techniques works smoothly, but OCR with Paddle OCR introduces a significant 10-second latency per frame.Using Python 3.10.6 and PaddleOCR version 2.6.1.
import cv2
import threading
from paddleocr import PaddleOCR

# Fixed frame size
frame_width = 640
frame_height = 480

# IP Camera URLs
url1 = "your_first_rtsp_url_here"
url2 = "your_second_rtsp_url_here"

# Function to read frames from the cameras
def read_frames(url, camera_number):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print(f"Error: Unable to open camera {camera_number}.")
        return
    
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print(f"Error: Unable to read frame from camera {camera_number}.")
            break
        
        # Resize the frame to fixed size
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (frame_width, frame_height))
        
        # Display the frame
        cv2.imshow(f"Camera {camera_number}", frame)
        
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  # Press 'q' to quit
            break
    
    cap.release()

# Function to process frames
def process_frames(url, camera_number):
    ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang='en')
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print(f"Error: Unable to open camera {camera_number}.")
        return
    
    frame_count = 0  # Initialize frame count
    
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print(f"Error: Unable to read frame from camera {camera_number}.")
            break
        
        # Increment frame count
        frame_count += 1
        
        # Check if it's the 5th frame
        if frame_count % 5 == 0:
            # Resize the frame to fixed size
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (frame_width, frame_height))
            
            result = ocr.ocr(frame, cls=True)

            for idx in range(len(result)):
                res = result[idx]
                if res != None:
                    for line in res:
                        print(f"Text: {line[1][0]}")

                        # Extract and parse bounding box coordinates
                        bbox = line[0]
                        bbox_top_left = (int(bbox[0][0]), int(bbox[0][1]))
                        bbox_bottom_right = (int(bbox[2][0]), int(bbox[2][1]))

                        # Draw bounding box and text on the frame
                        cv2.rectangle(frame, bbox_top_left, bbox_bottom_right, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                        cv2.putText(frame, line[1][0], bbox_top_left, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)

            # Display the processed frame
            cv2.imshow(f"Processed Frame {camera_number}", frame)
        
        # Check for 'q' key press to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    
    cap.release()

# Main function
def main():
    # Start reading frames from camera 1 in a separate thread
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=read_frames, args=(url1, 1))
    thread1.start()
    
    # Start reading frames from camera 2 in a separate thread
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=read_frames, args=(url2, 2))
    thread2.start()

    # Start processing frames from camera 1 in a separate thread
    process_thread1 = threading.Thread(target=process_frames, args=(url1, 1))
    process_thread1.start()
    
    # Start processing frames from camera 2 in a separate thread
    process_thread2 = threading.Thread(target=process_frames, args=(url2, 2))
    process_thread2.start()
    
    # Wait for the threads to finish
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
    process_thread1.join()
    process_thread2.join()
    
    # Close all OpenCV windows
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Tried optimizing OCR process but latency persists.Utilizing threading for performance optimization
Seeking insights on reducing latency for efficient text extraction

Have you tried profiling the code to figure out what step/line introduces the most latency? What were your results? OCR can be more computationally heavy than basic operations like blurring.
